# @nuxt/auth can I send refresh token using params?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, jwt, nuxt.js, refresh-token

I have a problem with [@nuxt/auth module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module). I already use the `refresh scheme`, in the refresh method, the module sends the refresh token in a `Payload Request` but I want to send it in the params.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `auth` plugin is not very flexible and looking at this, I'm not sure that this is quite customizable: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/refresh#refreshtoken

If you can edit your backend to accomodate to how this module work, it will maybe be easier.

On the other side, there is [`refreshController`](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/refreshController#usage) but I don't really know how this one works nor if it can help you. This github issue may help I hope: https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/924